# Model function call in a Template

Tags: laravel

I have model called Page and view called view.blade.php

```
//this is a model
public function Test()
{
    return 'test';
}
```

```
//this is the template
<h1>{{$Test}}</h1>
```

how can I do this? please help me?

Comment: Could you show the controller you are using to load this view?

Comment: I'm new to laravel. is the controller is required to do this task?

Comment: Where are you returning this view?

Answer (score 1):

As I understood, you want to call model function inside your view? Do it like this:

```
{{Page::Test()}}
```

Edit:

If you need to use `$this` in your function to pass some data for your function (if that was what you were asking in comments below), you can do something like this. First define your static function:

```
public static function getPages()
    {
        return [
            //some logic (get all pages)
        ];
    }
```

Now, let's say this function will return multiple pages. If you want to filter them, and to display only one page on your view, you can pass the id of that view as a parameter to a next function which you will then pass to your view:

```
public function getSinglePage()
    {
        return self::getPages()[$this->id];
    }
```

Lastly, in order to display the output of that function, use the same method as above, with new function name:

```
{{Page::getSinglePage()}}
```

Comment: can use this as only static functions??

Comment: Didn't quite understand your question. Your `Test()` function is static, and you're asking if you can use it like this?

Comment: if i use this keyword in that function (non static function), how can i do that like these?

Comment: No problem, if this helped you in any way, mark it as an answer, so it can help future users with same problem.